# Cannot change max_function_args parameter in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I'm trying to modify the max_function_args parameter in PostgreSQL, but I'm getting an error message saying that the parameter cannot be changed. I'm using PostgreSQL version X.X on operating system Y.

I've checked my user role and confirmed that I have the necessary privileges to modify configuration settings, including the max_function_args parameter. However, when I run the SET max_function_args = 200; command, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: parameter "max_function_args" cannot be changed
```

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Are there any additional steps I need to take to modify the max_function_args parameter, or are there any restrictions or limitations that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Documentation this parameter **max_function_args** is red-only and cannot be changed. You cannot change this parameter without recompiling postgres.

REF: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-preset.html
The following “parameters” are read-only. As such, they have been excluded from the sample postgresql.conf file. These options report various aspects of PostgreSQL behavior that might be of interest to certain applications, particularly administrative front-ends. Most of them are determined when PostgreSQL is compiled or when it is installed.

Answer (score 2):

As previously said, the **max_function_args** is read-only and determined by the system configuration, which means that is a compile-time constant and cannot be changed dynamically or via a configuration file. The default value is 100 arguments.

So if you need to to work with a large number of function arguments, you may need to consider alternative approaches, such as restructuring your data model or using composite types or arrays to group related arguments together.

Remember that it's generally a good practice to keep the number of arguments manageable and consider alternative design patterns if you find yourself needing a significant number of function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

As other users have pointed out, the parameter is read-only. However, if you really want to change the number of parameters and are building your application for a personal project instead of for pushing into production, one thing you could do is download the source code, edit the parameter in the source code manually, and then build PostgreSQL from your source code.

Answer (score 0):

The `max_function_args` parameter in PostgreSQL is marked as immutable, which means it cannot be modified dynamically at runtime. In such cases, you need to change its value in the configuration file `postgresql.conf` and restart the PostgreSQL service for the new value to take effect.

You will need to recompile your PostgreSQL for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score -1):

This document https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-preset.html mentions a list of parameters which are read only.

The reason for the mentioned error is that max_function_args is read only, and therefore cannot be modified.